# C: Scanf Validation

Tags: c

Say I have

[number of rooms]

[room name] [num of item1] [num of item2]

...

[number of doors]

[room name] [L|R|U|D] [room name]

...

[start room] [exit room]

[move1]

[move2]

....

say I am using scanf,

```
scanf(" %d", &roomCount);

scanf(" %s %d %d", room_name, &item1No, &item2No);
```

etc...

How would I verify that the user input the correct input?

Thanks

Comment: what is meant by correct input?

Comment: say if i want %d , i wanna expect 10 instead of blah or 10 10 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int input ;
if (scanf("%d", (&input)) == 0)
{
    while (getchar() != '\n');    // Removes the offending characters that causes 
                                    // scanf to struck at error occured on future 
                                    // operations.
    printf(" \n Invalid value.\n") ;
}
```

So, if you wish to user to prompt again for input, keep it in a `while` and break it if the `scanf` returned value is not **0**. Hope this gives you an idea.

Answer (score 4):

Using `scanf` is almost always a bad idea: it doesn't distinguish between newlines and other whitespace, which makes it very easy not to know where you are in whatever thing you're trying to parse. Probably bettter: read in lines using `fgets` and feed each line to `sscanf`, checking the return value to make sure you got what you were looking for. Alternatively, use an actual parser: make your own using a parser generator like `flex`, or use some sort of XML for your data format and use an XML parser, or something.

It would probably be wise to design your data format so that it's harder for parsing to get out of sync without noticing, and to make the structure of the data more apparent to human readers.

Comment: +1, but I suspect the flex/XML/XML parser part is a bit of an overkill in this particular case ;)

Comment: Yeah, probably. On the other hand, I wouldn't be astonished if this particular case were to grow into something bigger and more complicated. It looks like a simple specification for the map of an interactive-fiction game; so maybe tomorrow the questioner will want to add descriptions to the rooms, and then conditions in which you're allowed to move from one to another, and then objects in the rooms, ... and pretty soon a proper parser will be looking quite appealing.

Answer (score 3):

Well, `scanf` does return the number of items read successfully. You can compare that value after every read to the number of items you were expecting.

A very simple example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int v;
    if ( scanf( "%d", &v ) != 1 ) {
      /* we know something went wrong */
    }    
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but if he's supposed to have three numbers on one line and one on the next, but actually has two numbers on each line, `scanf` won't see the difference.

Comment: @Gareth I fully agree. If the input data is anything more than trivial, the way to go is what you describe in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` isn't a good tool for interactive input.

Better to read your whole input line as text using `fgets`, then break it into tokens using `strtok` and convert each value using `strtol` or `strtoul`.  This will give you more control, and you don't have to worry about mistakenly accepting some bad input (for example, if someone enters "10p", `scanf` will successfully convert and assign the `10` and leave `p` in the input stream to foul up the next read; you'd probably want to reject the entire input outright).